# How do I collapse all subtasks in a SharePoint 2013 task list?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, tasks, task-list, customization

I'm using SharePoint 2013 to keep track of projects and their sub-tasks. But the view is getting pretty long and it would be nice to have a button to collapse all subtasks, leaving only the top-level parent tasks. Most to do lists have this functionality. I found a jQuery solution that didn't work, but I haven't found any other solutions. I'd rather not farm each project off to its own sub-site with it's own list.

Comment: its a strectxh but if you want to extend the front end functionality of the task list, load that snuppet or web part into a custom page layout with a div wrapper and ID, then use jquery to show and hide various sections.

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling with the jquery as it was getting looped.

Then found a response from Cristy on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542684/document-ready-function-being-called-over-and-over

To Use `$(window).load`

Below is the script.

Add it to Content Editor Webpart with in the script tag

```
function doCollapseTaskList() {
    $(".ms-commentcollapse-iconouter > img").each(function(){
        $(this).click();
    });
}
$(window).load(function () {
     doCollapseTaskList();
});
```

Good Luck